# How to get Visual Studio editor text with color formatting?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsx, vs-extensibility

I have a VS plug-in that currently takes the editor text by getting a `TextDocument` via `app.ActiveDocument.Object()` and then I get the text from that. This, however, is just plain text, and I'd like to have not just text but the color information (kind of like the RTF export). How can I get it?

Answer (score 1):

Cast EnvDTE.TextDocument.Selection to EnvDTE.TextSelection and then use EnvDTE.TextSelection.Move(point1, false) and EnvDTE.TextSelection.Move(point2, true) and then EnvDTE.TextSelection.Copy() to copy to the clipboard, which you should preserve saving its content before copying and then restoring when done.

Comment: Created an edit point with `doc.StartPoint`, then called `ep.Copy(doc.EndPoint)`, but it looks like the buffer is empty - calling `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Rtf)` after doing the above gives me an empty string.

Comment: Can you test if you paste it in Microsoft Word, do you get the colors?

Comment: Nope, I don't. Text buffer is ok, rtf buffer is empty.